# Make PHP Array From Dynamic Number of Columns Queried

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

I have a query which converts item rows of a series of IDs in MySQL table to columns, so the result has variable number of columns (VC). The only items that are not dynamic are the ID, FirstName, LastName. I know the number of variable items (n), which is part of the query.

what I want to do is to have a loop inside PHP while to add these variable columns to the PHP array.

something like this:

```
$someArray = [];

while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

array_push($someArray,[ 

  'ID' => $row['EmployeeID'],
  'FName' => $row['FName'],
  'MName' => $row['MName'],
  'LName' => $row['LName'],

-------Loop here --------
  'VC1' => $row['VC1'],
  'VC2' => $row['VC2'],
  'VC3' => $row['VC3'],
  'VC4' => $row['VC4'],
  'VC5' => $row['VC5'],
  ..............
  'VCn' => $row['VCn']
-------------------------

]);
}
```

I tried with PHP loop and could not figure out how to do it.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Show us the query, this sounds a little odd so it would help us understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `n` you can use for loop:

```
for($i = 1;$i <= $n; $i++) {
    $key = "VC" .$i;
    $someArray[$key] = $row[$key];
}
```

However, if you pushing the entire array in it may be better do modify your SQL query and do just:

```
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    array_push($someArray, $row)
```

Comment: Undefined constant `n`, make it `$n`

Comment: Thanks, it works after I saw your edited answer. thanks a lot.